# Mysql - date and time columns to datetime

Tags: mysql

I have been trying to merge date and time into datetime. My date is varchar and I need to have got one column datetime (as datetime)

My input is like that:

```
create table t1 (
date1 varchar (12),
time1 varchar (39));

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES
('01.Mar.2019', '11:30'),
('02.Mar.2019', '1:30'),
('03.Mar.2019', '0:30'),
('03.Mar.2019', '10:30');
```

And the desired results are below:

```
datetime1
01.Mar.2019 11:30:00
02.Mar.2019 01:30:00
03.Mar.2019 00:30:00
03.Mar.2019 10:30:00
```

Comment: **That SHOULD NOT be your desired output!!!** Use `DATETIME` datatype to store Date times. Then all the date functionality built into MySQL will work and make your life easier later when you want to porcess this data. Oh and use DATE for dates and TIME for times as well

Comment: I'm afraid I can't understand your question. What is `datetime1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(date1,' ',time1),'%d.%b.%Y %H:%i') x FROM t1;
+---------------------+
| x                   |
+---------------------+
| 2019-03-01 11:30:00 |
| 2019-03-02 01:30:00 |
| 2019-03-03 00:30:00 |
| 2019-03-03 10:30:00 |
+---------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I feel that the way you are storing these values is not the best solution, you can present the data in its current stored format as a `DATETIME` by using `CONCAT` to join the separate `VARCHAR`s together and then `STR_TO_DATE` to convert the string into a `DATETIME`:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(date1, ' ', time1), '%d.%b.%Y %k:%i') FROM t1;
```

This is broken into two parts:

```
CONCAT(date1, ' ', time1)
```

Joins the date and time together with a space into a single string that will look like this:

```
01.Mar.2019 11:30
02.Mar.2019 1:30
03.Mar.2019 0:30
03.Mar.2019 10:30
```

Then, `STR_TO_DATE` converts this to a `DATETIME` using format specifiers:

```
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(date1, ' ', time1), '%d.%b.%Y %k:%i')
```

So, the formats are:

> %d - Day of the month with leading zero if it is 1 number (01, 02, 03, and so on)
>
> %b - Three-characters abbreviated month name (Jan, Feb, Mar, and so on)
>
> %Y - Four digits year (2018, 2019, and so on)
>
> %k - Hour in 24-hour format without leading zero (0, 1, 2, and so on)
>
> %i - Minutes with leading zero (00, 01, 02, and so on)

The output from this will be:

```
2019-03-01 11:30:00
2019-03-02 01:30:00
2019-03-03 00:30:00
2019-03-03 10:30:00
```

I just want to add that I feel that the best way to store date and time information in the database is almost certainly to use a `DATETIME` column.